# Spring Security and Grails - customizing URLS for Heroku

Tags: spring, heroku, grails, google-oauth, grails-plugin

I am using the following plugin: https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2

And I configurated it that way in my application.yml:

```
grails:
  plugin:
    springsecurity:
        oauth2:
            active: true
            domainClass: 'myapp.OAuthID'
            providers:
                google:
                    api_key: '...'
                    api_secret: '...'
```

It's working very well in localhost, but when I deployed my project in Heroku, the button for Sign-In with Google return a callback in the localhost environment. Why? I don't know.

I will see the Google account in my browser but when I clicked in any account, the server redirects to http://localhost:8080/...

I think this issue is due to the Procfile file or the Plugin config. How to solve this?

*Procfile* file

```
web: cd build ; java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx256m -Dgrails.env=prod -jar ../build/server/webapp-runner-*.jar --expand-war --port $PORT libs/*.war
```

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to add the server URL into the config file like that:

```
grails:
   serverURL: ${HOST_NAME}
```

The HOST_NAME is an environment variable.